# How to make an input box be centred within a container without the label pushing it down?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a search box that looks like this[image]

where there is a container with multiple input fields that have labels above. My problem is I want the centre of the input to be centred within the container rather than the label+input combined like I currently have.[image]

my code is:

```
 <form className='searchContainer'>

             <div className="searchinner">
                 <label>Where To?</label><br/>
                 <input type="text" className="block" placeholder="Location" />
             </div>

             <div className="searchinner">
                 <label>Date</label><br/>
                 <input className="block" placeholder="Any" />
             </div>

             <div className="searchinner">
                 <label>Number of Guests</label><br/>
                 <select className='block' >
                     <option value="Any">Any</option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                     <option value="6">6</option>
                 </select>
          </div>
             <div className='searchinner'>
             <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-mobile' >.   <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline' buttonSize='btn--     medium'>Search</Button></Link>
             </div>
        </form>
```

my css is:

```
.searchContainer{
width: 60%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 10vh;
height: 12vh;
background: lightgrey;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
}

.block{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? you want your design to be like the first image? because I don't see any different between them.

Comment: In my picture the input box is slightly below centre because the label pushes it down. I would like the centre on my input box to be inline with the centre of my search box.

Comment: you don't need to do that. if it was me, I would create a container which has 2 elements. 1 is that little text below and another which is the first element is the container of the fileds. now, the second container that holds the fields will be display as flexbox and has 4 elements. first 3 are the inputs and label div and the last one is that search button. now if I give `flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-end;` to the container of the fields, it's going to be the same of the first image. now, I'm tying to make a fiddle of that, until then try it yourself.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you shared your code it will be easy to tell and do for community.

You achieve this by positioning label as `absolute` and `input` as `relative` .
So now label will not take space and will be positioned using `left/right/top/bottom` values according to need .
As label is now not taking space due to `position : absolute` .

Now your `input` will be centered according to container

Comment: You should share complete code which make output same as in the image shared by you in your question